# How to use or in while loop?

Tags: matlab, logical-operators

I really have no idea how to use this

```
  while  flag==1 or n<3000 
         n=n+1
  end
```

And it reports:

```
??? Error using ==> or
Not enough input arguments.
```

This problem is so basic, but I can't find any examples. I search for `matlab or`, but `or` got ommited in google. I'm sorry I really got no idea about its syntax.

Comment: Next time search for "logical operators" (http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logicaloperatorsshortcircuit.html)

Comment: If my answer helped you, please make it as an Answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write it this way

```
   while  (flag==1) || (n<3000 )
         n=n+1;
  end
```

Comment: By the way AND is written :"&&"

Answer (score 4):

The straightforward answer is that you should write

```
while  (flag==1) || (n<3000)
    n=n+1;
end
```

instead. `||` is for "or", and `&&` is for "and".

Why did you get the error message you were seeing? Well, although it's not often used directly, there is actually a MATLAB function `or`, and `||` is just shorthand for `or`. But to call `or` directly, you have to use it as a function. So

```
while or(flag==1, n<3000)
    n=n+1;
end
```

would work as well. When you call it as `flag==1 or n<3000`, it doesn't have input arguments and errors as you saw.